# How to store checkbox value as 1 and 0

Tags: php, html

It doesn't stores value in my database. It always stores "0" value even if i checked the item.

Here is my code:

```
          <input type="checkbox" name="parental" <?php $parental = (isset($_POST['parental'])) ? 0 : 1;?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="parental" />
```

Comment: Where is the `value` attribute? Also, whats the `type` of the DB column

Comment: dont use same name for two fields. give separate name for checkbox and input

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the attribute `value` and also add `echo` in php code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="parental" value="<?php echo $parental = (isset($_POST['parental'])) ? 0 : 1;?>" />
```

also why you have this element?

```
<input type="hidden" name="parental" />
```

It will overwrite the checkbox since both have the same name, either remove the hidden element or change the name

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="parental" value="<?php echo $parental = (isset($_POST['parental'])) ? 1 : 0;?>" /><input type="hidden" name="parental" />

Comment: here is my query: $parental = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['parental']));

Comment: so is `$_POST['parental']` set?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, checkbox value should always be the same, in your case 1, since checkbox passes it's value when it is checked, and does not when it is not. Also, if you want to use hidden field, you should use it before checkbox, so in case checkbox is not checked, it still passes 0.

For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="parental" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="parental" value="1" />
```

If the checkbox is checked $_POST["parental"] will equal 1, else it will equal 0. There are better ways to achieve this in php after the submit, though.

Also, regarding your conditional, I suppose you want to check the checkbox if parental is 1, which you should do like this, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="parental" value="1" <? echo $_POST["parental"]=="1"?"checked":""; ?> />
```

Changing input type checkbox value, does not really have much sense in your case, if I understood right.

Comment: I understood that from the question, but I wanted to point out that changing the checkbox value makes no sense. Even if it is set to 0 it will not post the 0, unless it is checked. That is why I suggested using the hidden field. I had a feeling that the question was not asked right, especially seeing the hidden field under the checkbox, which again makes no sense, because it would overwrite the checkbox value anyway.

Comment: here is my code:     
    <input type="checkbox" name="parental" value="<?php echo $parental = (isset($_POST['parental'])) ? 1 : 0;?>" />
                 <input type="hidden" name="parental" />

Comment: You should really try to explain better what you are trying to do, and edit your question to be proper. What your php outputs is

<input type="checkbox" value="parental=(1 or 0)" />

which I doubt is what you are looking for.

Comment: Im making a requirements checklist, I want to store the value of the checked item in my database as an int vale which is 1 / 0. But it doesnt store anything. I have my hp code and sql query. here it goes

https://www.mediafire.com/?ck1no31zzaj3tb0

Comment: See my first response. As I said, when checkbox is checked, after POST, you have it's value in $_POST["checkboxname"]. If it is not checked, then $_POST["checkboxname"] does not exist. It is simple as that. You should really rewrite your code to reflect this.